# Google Calendar API where to get service object from code?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Hello i have the code example which is from Google developer website:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events

```
public void addEventToCalendar() {

        Event event = new Event()
                .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
                .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
                .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.");

        DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00");
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
        event.setStart(start);

        DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00");
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(endDateTime)
                .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
        event.setEnd(end);

        String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"};
        event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

        EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
                new EventAttendee().setEmail("lpage@example.com"),
                new EventAttendee().setEmail("sbrin@example.com"),
        };
        event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));

        EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
                new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
                new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
        };
        Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                .setUseDefault(false)
                .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
        event.setReminders(reminders);

        String calendarId = "primary";
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
        System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
    }
```

I dont know where to get the service object.

See:

```
service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
```

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

See [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) example:

```
    private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService = null;
    ......
    public void initialize(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Android Quickstart")
                .build();
    }
```

Tutorial also [contains](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android#step_5_setup_the_sample) code snippet to get `GoogleAccountCredential` object to instantiate your `mService`.

Then you can `insert()` new event(like you do in your code), or, for example get existing ones:

```
  Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();
```

I hope, it helps. Happy New Year!